# GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() It is possible to know if Update button has pressed?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm searching in Google and Stack Overflow. Can't find any info about this.

I need to know if the user has pressed update button in dialog generated by `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()`.

No documentation about it in android.developers, no info in Google.

Comment: what for? check if is not canceled... if not ... check again if you have a proper version of GooglePS

Comment: i need to check it because i must do different logic in my app in the background if the button is pressed

Comment: then show your own dialog ... also why you reposting the questios? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000359/how-to-handle-googleplayservicesutil-geterrordialog-dialog-cancel-or-back-key

Comment: that question is for back and dissmiss not for update button......